# How to add to existing attribute?

Tags: javascript

Is there something equivalent to:

`.setAttribute()` that adds to the `attribute` something like:
`.addToAttribute()`

Instead of resetting the entire attribute value… it adds to the current value.

**Heads up**
The attribute could be anything: name, id, title… etc.
I need to add to any attribute at will and not just to the `class`

## What I have

```js
function one() {
body = document.body
div = document.createElement('div')
body.appendChild(div)
div.setAttribute("class", "blue")
div.setAttribute("name", "John")
div.setAttribute("id", "box")
}
one()



//should be
//name="John new value"
div.setAttribute("name", "new value")
// Is there something equivalent to .setAttribute()?
// Like .addToAttribue()?



console.log(document.getElementById('box'))
```

```css
.blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  background: blue;
}
[name~="value"] {
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

## What it should log

```js
function one() {
body = document.body
div = document.createElement('div')
body.appendChild(div)
div.setAttribute("class", "blue")
div.setAttribute("name", "name")
div.setAttribute("id", "box")
}
one()



div.setAttribute("name", "John new value")
console.log(document.getElementById('box'))
```

```css
.blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  background: blue;
}
[name~="value"] {
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
function addToAttribute(element, attributeName, value) {
    element.setAttribute(
        attributeName, 
        (element.getAttribute(attributeName) || '') + value);
}
```

Example:

```js
function addToAttribute(element, attributeName, value) {
  element.setAttribute(
attributeName, 
(element.getAttribute(attributeName) || '') + value);
}

function one() {
  var body = document.body
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  body.appendChild(div)
  div.setAttribute("class", "blue")
  div.setAttribute("name", "name")
  div.setAttribute("id", "box")
}
one()

var div = document.getElementById('box');
addToAttribute(div, "name", "John new value")
console.log(div);
```

```css
.blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  background: blue;
}
[name~="value"] {
border-radius: 50%;
}
```